# How to have a new record's isDirty flag set to false

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my `willTransition` hook I am using `isDirty` to determine whether a modal should display a warning to the user that they will lose unsaved changes if they navigate away. The problem is, a new record in Ember is considered dirty before even adjusting any of the fields. I need a way to override this behavior. I have tried the following without success:

First I tried creating my own flag that observes when the model is changed and sets an `isNasty` flag to true. I thought this might work because I'm omitting `.on('init')` but unfortunately this is set for a new record immediately.

```
// app/controllers/foo.js
...
isNasty: false,

modelIsEdited: function () {
  this.set('isNasty', true);
}.observes('model')
```

Next I thought a combination of the `isDirty` flag and `isNew` would do the trick, which did technically work partly. But the problem arises if you then enter fields into the new record, it will never prompt with the modal:

```
// app/routes/foo.js
...
willTransition: function() {
  if (this.controller.get('isDirty') && !this.controller.get('isNew') {
     ...
  }
}
```

The same problem presents itself with the `dirtyType` property (checking it's `created`).

Finally I tried manually setting the `isDirty` flag to false after creation of the model, however as it's a read-only property this didn't work either.

```
// app/routes/foo.js
...
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model.demo);
  controller.set('isDirty', false);
  // This throws an error as isDirty is a read-only property
}
```

Comment: So you don't want users to be warned, if they abandon a new model they were creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want this:

```
if ((model.isDirty && !model.isNew) || (model.isNew && model.isFilledIn)) {}
```

If that's the case, we already have 2 out of those 3 states, so we just need to come up with a way to create the `isFilledIn` state (or whatever you want to call it).  I haven't used Ember-Data in a very long time, but I think this will work:

```
isFilledIn: function() {
    // `this._attributes` holds new values for attributes on the model.
    // Because the model is new, all attributes are new, so if any
    // attributes have been set, they'll be in here.
    return Ember.keys(this._attributes) > 0;
}.property().volatile() // don't try to observe this property
```

Now you can tell if your model is old and modified, or it's new but has some of the attributes set. (You'll have to do some more work for relationships.)

Comment: Thank you, I used it basically as you instructed with a few modifications. For each of the `model` checks in the `if` statement I used `get()`, so `model.get('isDirty')`. And then the return statement was always returning false, it again seems you need to use `this.get('_attributes')` but this would still always be false, so I appended `.length` so the entire line ended up as `return Ember.keys(this.get('_attributes')).length > 0;`. This solves my problem, thanks!